# Laravel 5.8 route not defined but it clearly is

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

before i post this question, it's running well.
but some time, when i continue to develop my laravel project, i face this problem.

> The Error : Route [user/alamat/2] not defined.

```php
//Routes
//web.php
Route::get('user/alamat/{id}','UserTransaksiController@index')->name('user/alamat/{id}');


//Blade
<a href={{ route('user/alamat/'.Auth::user()->iduser) }} >
```

Answer (score 0):

the route function you are using in your blade is for route names. You cannot pass a parameter when you are naming your route you can name your route like `user.alamat` and in your blade template you can use `route('user.alamat', auth()->id())`.

Pass parameters as an array in your `route('name', [$yourParameters])`.

```
Route::get('user/alamat/{id}','UserTransaksiController@index')->name('user.alamat');
```

```
<a href="{{ route('user.alamat', auth()->id()) }}" ></a>

<!-- OR -->

<a href="/user/alamat/{{ auth()->id() }}" ></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Azimi,

but, why code {{ route('user/alamat/'.Auth::user()->iduser) }} cant detect route in web.php ?

Comment: Because there is no route name called `user/alamat/1` your route name is actually LITERALLY called `user/alamat/{id}` as a string form.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go step by step on the things you should refactor.

First of all you should rename your route. The name method should be something like this.

```php
Route::get('user/alamat/{id}','UserTransaksiController@index')->name('user.alamat');
```

Then you can reference your route from anywhere in your application using that same name in your example it should be like this (note how to call the parameters):

```
<a href="{{ route('user.alamat', ['id' => auth()->user()->id]) }}" ></a>
```

At this point the error should be solved, if you want to improve your code you can read further.

Going back to your route It makes no sense for me to have a **alamat** in your routes and **Transaksi** on your controller. Depending on the information you are going to retrieve, they should be consistent to make the code readable. Lets say you are retrieving **Transaksi** which I saw translates to **Deal** so you should have something like this.

```php
Route::get('users/{id}/transaksis','UserTransaksiController@index')->name('user.transaksi.index');
```

Note that I changed the route a little bit more. `Route::get('user/{id}/transaksis'....` this section is read as if you want to get something related to users, then the id of that specific user and then the other related model. Using this same principle, the name should be `...->name('user.transaksi.index')`

I used **index** on the name because you cant have more methods on the same controller and the routing names should also be consistent for readability.

Finally you can go to the `RouteServiceProvider` and whit-in the boot method add this. `Route::model('user', User::class);` with this you can change your route to be like this:

```php
Route::get('users/{user}/transaksis','UserTransaksiController@index')->name('user.transaksis.index');
```

This is called Route Model Binding and it allows you to get the entire model in your controller like this:

```php
public function index(User $user)
{
    //user should have the entire user model instance

    //if you have relations defined you can do this
    $user->transaksis;

    //the rest of your code to return goes here
}
```

I did all this as an example considering that User could be any other model. If you want to simplify it for your specific case you can get the user id from within the controller without passing it as a parameter like this:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //Option 1 using the user from the request (you do not need to pass the request from the route, it is filled automatically by LAravel
    $request->user()->transaksis;

    //Option 2 using the auth helper
    auth()->user()->transaksis;

    //There are a lot of options to get the user

    //the rest of your code to return goes here
}
```